# Drupal: jQuery media module: how can I pass object ID?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using jQuery-media module to embed my flash player. How can I pass the current  id using the FlashVars ?

I can only write static string in jquery Media advanced settings, but I would like to pass the object id, maybe some token ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved adding this to the jquery media code

> opts.flashvars  = [el.id];